# Granular timestamps in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache 2.4 introduced [sub-second granularity for log timestamps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html), so you can do things like

```
LogFormat "%{%d/%b/%Y %T}t.%{msec_frac}t %{%z}t [...]
```

As far as I can tell, this feature is not available natively in Apache 2.2.  We're not ready to upgrade to 2.4 yet, but I'd still like to have granular timestamps.

Is there a way of getting this functionality in Apache 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.2 supports `strftime(3)`.

However https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats:

> The extended strftime(3) tokens are available in **2.2.30** and later.

This is a really old question, but since there exists, among others, RHEL6 (and perhaps even RHEL5) out there still, the default httpd / apache install on those platforms is `apache 2.2.15`, thus no support for `msec_frac`.

*The usual about one should have updated, etc, etc.*

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says this feature should exists in apache 2.2

```
%{format}t  | The time, in the form given by format, which should be in strftime(3) format. (potentially localized)
```

take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html.

Comment: But, as I read it, nothing in `strftime` suggests it offers sub-second timing.

Comment: both documentations talk about strftime(3) formatation, so they should support the same tokens. maybe you should simply try it in apache 2.2.

Comment: The Apache 2.4 docs say '*In addition to the formats supported by strftime(3)*, the following format tokens are supported:', and goes on to list `msec_frac`.